# Add lang-clj syntax-highlighting to [clojure] [clojurescript] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

The [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) and [clojurescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojurescript) tags (at least) should have a lang-clj syntax-highlighting hint. I don't know what they have now, but it's wrong.

Comment: They're currently set to lang-lisp. We actually can't update this right now because lang-clj is not available in our selection menu as an option (they don't always update that list when they add new languages).

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) has a lang-lisp hint (which makes sense on first blush, since the tag wiki says Clojure is a dialect of Lisp), while [clojurescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojurescript) does not have any.

For some reason, if you add a hint, it works, but I cannot find lang-clj in the list of default hints to use, so unfortunately I cannot complete this for you.

Perhaps the prettify script that we use is up to date but our backend isn't. I'll have to harass the devs about this.

Comment: I confirmed that using "language: lang-clj" results in the correct highlighting, and clojure is supported [according to the FAQ of the prettify readme](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), so most likely the list is out of date.

Comment: @Francis It definitely is. There's quite a few of them missing, and even some synonyms in there that ultimately go to the same highlighter. Seems like, being a moderator-only option, it'd just be easier to reference the FAQ and use a text field to let us enter it instead.

Comment: Looks like lang-clj has been added at some point in the last year.