# Wrong default syntax highlighting in some tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that two of my favorite tags have the wrong [syntax highlighting](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) assigned to them:

- [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) has `lang-lisp` syntax highlighter instead of `lang-clj`;
- [coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript) has `lang-default` syntax highlighter instead of `lang-coffee`.

Named syntax highlighters:

- [lang-clj](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-clj.js)
- I can't find `lang-coffee` highlighter in docs, but according to [this answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109), it is supported. I tested it on SO and it works fine.

I found no way to edit or suggest syntax highlighter for a tag in SO interface. Having such an option will help us keep syntax highlighting up to date.

It'd also be great to support [`lang-matlab` highlighter](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-matlab.js), to serve as the default for the [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag. Right now it's not in the [list of supported highlighters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Comment: `coffee` is a synonym for `coffeescript`; did you mean the latter?

Comment: I don't think there's any such thing as `lang-matlab`. But these defaults can be changed by moderators, so posting here is an appropriate way to be heard.

Comment: There is no `lang-matlab`; the `lang-clj` and `lang-coffee` languages are relatively newer, the `clojure` and `coffeescript` tag defaults were probably set before they became available.

Comment: @CodyGray there is, [here it is](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-matlab.js).

Comment: @MartijnPieters and [here is the one for clojure](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-clj.js).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find `coffee` highlighter in docs, but I've seen it some time ago and `<!-- language: lang-coffee -->` works perfect on SO.

Comment: Updated my question with this info.

Comment: See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108) for what is currently supported on Stack Exchange sites; `lang-clj` and `lang-coffee` are there, `lang-matlab` is not yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I already tested `lang-matlab` on SO and it works. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25359656/1202461).

Comment: FYI, [clojure] was reported last week - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269222/add-lang-clj-syntax-highlighting-to-clojure-clojurescript-tags I think it's fine to tag it [feature-request].

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: I wouldn't call that 'works'; comments are not highlighted correctly. That's just the default highlighter making a guess and guessing wrong. You could put in `lang-foobar` there and get the exact same result.

Comment: @BoltClock thanx!

Comment: @MartijnPieters probably you're right...

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, looks like it's a default one

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have a feeling that `lang-matlab` actually worked last week... Default highlighting for `matlab` code also changed a bit. Looks like there is some work in progress.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: when a specific language highlighter is picked, you'll see `class="lang-xxx prettyprint prettyprinted"` on the `<pre>` tag surrounding the highlighted text. Look for that when checking what, if any, highlighter has been applied. Note that using `<!-- language: lang-... -->` overrides any default picked, so pick a post without such a hint.

Comment: [Lang-matlab exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language) @Martijn; just supposedly not implemented.

Comment: @Ben it's not simply exists, it's already a [part of `google-code-prettify` lib](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-matlab.js).

Comment: I know, that fact is what I link to but it must be explicitly pulled and enabled by SE before it's _used_ @Leonid.

Comment: One year later (that's some timing...), Matlab highlighting still hasn't been pulled in, and no response whatsoever to a more recent feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting. A little feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "`lang-matlab` is not [supported] yet"... So how do we *get* it supported? The code is there, and has been for over 3 years, but we need the devs to pull it in. The question in my previous comment has gotten a lot of upvotes, but no feedback as to how to make it actually happen.

Comment: @beaker: I don't know. Have you tried creating a feature request to have prettify updated?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you suggesting https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md, or this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language?

Comment: @beaker: the latter. Find a dev to poke and ask?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't happen to know any, but thanks. :)

Comment: @beaker: start here: http://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering. Loads of names are linked to SE accounts. Find em in chat. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Cool. Thanks for your time. I'll get the MATLAB chat room on it. :)