# MATLAB syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) I understand that syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow is done using [Google's prettify project](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md), which [does support MATLAB syntax](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-matlab.js).

Despite this, the MATLAB information page still specifies `Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): default` at the bottom.

Even if I use `<!-- language: lang-matlab -->` before a code block, the syntax highlighting doesn't work correctly.

For the most part, this isn't that big a deal, but the MATLAB matrix transpose operator is `'`, which makes the code highlighter think that everything between a pair of `'` characters is a string. This can really make code hard to read.

```matlab
a = 1:5;
b = a';
C = a*b;
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        R(i,j) = rand();
    end
end
d = det(C'*R);
```

Can we get MATLAB syntax highlighting?

Comment: As well as the comment kludge `%//` since `%` isn't recognized as the start of a comment.

Comment: See also [this question on StackOverflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269708/wrong-default-syntax-highlighting-in-some-tags) and the comments there (click "show more comments" to get them all). Apparently [Matlab syntax highlighting in prettify works through an extension](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), and Stack Exchange doesn't support it so far.

Comment: status completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279440/158100

Comment: That splendid working conjugate transpose on `C`! It looks gorgeous!

Answer (score 14):

MATLAB syntax highlighting is now live!

[Add syntax highlighting for the MATLAB language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language/279440#279440)

This is the "lite" version of [@Amro's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) prettify script which does not include complete keyword highlighting (the full script was a bit too large), but the major annoyances like transpose and commenting appear to be fixed.

```matlab
a = 1:5;   % Comments properly highlighted
b = a';
%{         % Block comments also work
C = a*b;
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        R(i,j) = rand();
    end
end
%}
d = det(C'*R);   % Transpose doesn't act as quote
s = 'This is a test.';   % but strings are still properly highlighted
```

Comment: * complex conjugate transpose (before I get jumped on). ;)

Comment: Finally I can answer questions without appending `//` to comments or having to worry about transposing as "stray comments"... and block comments, yes!

Answer (score -6):

I am not sure why `<!-- language: lang-matlab -->` does not work; but the tag-wiki for [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) also says:

> Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)): `default`

but the code snippets can be highlighted using `lang-golang` (as opposed to the obvious `lang-go`.

---

Testing with MATLAB code, I notice that we can use `lang-m` (I'm not sure whether it actually highlights code with MATLAB syntax or not):

```m
a = 1:5;
b = a';
C = a*b;
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        R(i,j) = rand();
    end
end
% comment to test
d = det(C'*R);
```

Comment: This is the default highlighting; there's no recognition of comments. `lang-go` does supposedly exist, `lang-golang` would use the default again.

Comment: `lang-m` doesn't highlight MATLAB code correctly. Note the `*R);` which is highlighted in red (as a string) because of the `'` (transpose operator) which is also used to denote strings in MATLAB like `'mystring'`. The comment is also not correctly highlighted which can lead people to use `%//` instead.

Comment: @IKavanagh That is an issue specific to the code-prettify library itself. You can test it locally by using https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Comment: @IKavanagh Check the fiddle for eg: http://jsfiddle.net/ndx3j106/

Comment: But SE hasn't added the MATLAB extension, so you're testing the wrong version. That's the point of the question.