# Enable XQuery syntax highlighting (Prettify lang-xq.js)

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I recently tried to add `<!-- language: lang-xq -->` to properly syntax-highlight a snippet of XQuery code in a StackOverflow question:

```xq
for $n in Movies//Movie//OtherTitles
    let $d := ($n/OtherTitleName/text(),$n/Year/text())
        return $d
    (: let $d := concat($n/OtherTitleName/text(),$n/Year/text()) <- Gives me error :)
```

Notably, comments in XQuery are delimited by `(:` and `:)`. However, the above snippet appears as of this writing to be treating `//` as a line-oriented comment delimiter (which it is not in XQuery), and failing to recognize `(:` or `:)`.

This mechanism for specifying a language [is documented in the editing-help site](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), and `lang-xq` [is present in the Prettify source base](https://github.com/pvorb/google-code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-xq.js) and correctly recognizes `(:` and `:)` as comments (see line 49 as of current master). Thus, it appears that the language specification is not being honored; is this a usage error?

---

#### Update: Feature request

Per feedback from [Ben](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/458741/ben):

> If it's a separate JS file then SE explicitly integrate it, cf [MATLAB](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287407/458741). XQuery doesn't have highlighting enabled (see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/179419) for how to find out and more info). Change this into a feature request to add the highlighting. – Ben 45 mins ago

Comment: SE / SO do not maintain the highlighter. Moreover, I don't think that's even using XQuery highlighting -- it looks like PHP highlighting, with Capitalised Class and Object names in bright blue

Comment: @cat, yes, that's the problem I'm requesting support with -- I'm (to the best of my knowledge) specifying the highlighter in the manner documented in the SO Help Center, yet it's not using XQuery highlighting.

Comment: @cat, ...indeed, the highlighter is a third-party component, but you'll note that I provided a link to the relevant source of that component, down to the specific line of source that would be causing things to work as intended if the correct language were in fact in use.

Comment: If it's a separate JS file then SE explicitly integrate it, cf [MATLAB](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287407/458741). XQuery doesn't have highlighting enabled (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/179419 for how to find out and more info). Change this into a feature request to add the highlighting.

Comment: Instead of adding yet another FR to the pile of tiny improvements you might consider supporting  the FR to implement [highlight-js](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please)

Comment: In addition to @rene's comment, note that highlight.js already supports XQuery highlighing so the proposed changed would also solve this issue.

Comment: Note that there are a lot of FRs to add languages that Prettify *already supports* that have gotten no traction with SO staff. This will probably be another of them.