# Customizable syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that the syntax highlighting theme has been changed recently, while I don't particularly the new theme I was wondering what about having the possibility to customize the syntax highlight colors through the preferences of the profile.

I don't mean having the ability to customize the regular expressions that regulate what is a keyword or a literal or whatever but just the ability to customize the colors (and maybe the background of the code snippet.)

From a difficulty point of view it sounds like having some color pickers for the various categories (keywords, numbers, literals, whatever) applied through a CSS to the whole site.

I understand that this is completely optional but it would be nice to be able to use the same colors I use in my IDEs here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already do this, via third party browser plugins which modify the stylesheet directly on the site for you. Just install one you like and then you can customize all the colors yourself by simply overriding the styles for each class. There's no need for us to implement complicated options for choosing your own color sets when you can easily do this in your browser without those options.

Comment: With the risk of sounding like a grumpy old man waving a stick (which I am, when it comes to this issue), will this be the eventual official answer for [MATLAB's syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting), first requested [4 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language)? With the new default highlighting rules, it's broken more than ever.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Two completely separate issues. That doesn't work because we don't have the Matlab module loaded into our Prettify file. It needs to be added if the code will ever get parsed correctly. No amount of extra CSS on the client's part would fix that.

Comment: @animuson So... is there a Matlab module available? Why isn't it loaded into the Prettify file?

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit confused because [Amro has a userscript that could fix it on the client end](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137865/313143) (and incidentally, he also worked out google-prettify support?). Can you tell me if there's any official channel over which somebody can be bugged to add the matlab module?:) With almost 60k posts in the [tag:matlab] tag, we're very desperate.

Comment: @AndrasDeak At the moment, I believe the dev team is looking into whether or not we can switch to Highlight.js from prettify, which would include a bunch of new languages anyways.

Comment: Thank you, in this case I'm standing by. (I promise not to bug you in the following 6-8 weeks;)