# Syntax highlighting for [octave] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Would it be possible to add syntax highlighting for the [octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave) tag?

We have [syntax highlighting for MATLAB](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting). It's the same language, so this should be trivial to add.

Most Octave questions are also tagged as MATLAB, so they get proper syntax highlighting, but that is not appropriate for some questions that are specific for Octave, and it's not right to add a MATLAB tag to those.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’ve set the default highlighter for the [octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave) tag to `lang-matlab`.