# Syntax Highlighting for Neo4j / Cypher questions

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

The [cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher) query language used in the [neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j) database is getting more and more traction as it has been "standardised" into [Open Cypher](http://www.opencypher.org), an initiative by multiple graph database vendors.

I think it would be worth thinking about syntax highlighting for [cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher) or [neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j) questions on Stack Overflow. For example:

- [how do I delete duplicate relationships between two nodes with cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202197/how-do-i-delete-duplicate-relationships-between-two-nodes-with-cypher)

Comment: You have my full support, but [matlab syntax highlighting's still not a thing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting), and that tag has 53k questions and `prettify` support...

Comment: I remember that non-users can flip the switch... we need a non-user!

Comment: Isn't syntax highlighting done via [Google Prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/261760)?  Doesn't that mean there's nothing SO can do about it?

Comment: @Teepeemm lies, all lies;) See, for instance, [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269708/wrong-default-syntax-highlighting-in-some-tags#comment84278_269708) to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269708/wrong-default-syntax-highlighting-in-some-tags) (partly matlab syntax highlighting question from *last year*). The bottleneck has long ago transferred from prettify to SO.