# Support Kotlin with syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Since [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) is now on [1.0](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/02/kotlin-1-0-released-pragmatic-language-for-jvm-and-android/), support for syntax highlighting of this JVM language would be nice. Answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35445704/5547025) would much benefit from this feature.

Comment: [kotlin has 671 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin), [MATLAB has 57121](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) and no syntax highlighting either.

Comment: Which syntax highlighter is the best match? Choose one from the [supported list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100).

Comment: If an already supported language matches the same or similar style of highlighting, you can _force_ it within the code snippet. Not saying that's the answer - obviously it would be nicer still to not have to manually do it, but just an option.

Comment: @Adriaan this is the status quo right now, Kotlin is version 1.0 while Matlab 8.6, Kotlin is free to use while Matlab is a pricey product. I think a one dimension comparison is misleading in this case.

Comment: MATLAB is supported by prettify (and has been since 2013). It would be odd if stack overflow did not also support it.
https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-matlab.js

Comment: @mlk [It has been asked on meta almost a year ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting) lots of upvotes and bled to death over time.

Comment: @Matt It would be nice if we could get even a *comment* from a mod regarding MATLAB syntax highlighting on the question linked by Adriaan. After all, it's been 4 years now... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language

Comment: @beaker: MATLAB syntax highlighting isn't something a moderator can do. Per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170264, a dev needs to update the version of the prettify library Stack Overflow uses, and/or make lang-matlab available for moderators to select.

Comment: @Matt Cool, thanks for the response (and I mean that sincerely). So how do we get a dev to look at the request and give some sort of feedback? Or do we need to open a duplicate request on meta.stackexchange?

Comment: @beaker: Daniel has brought http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting back to the first page by editing it. There's a chance that someone at SE HQ will notice it that way...

Comment: @Matt I tried that in August with [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269708/wrong-default-syntax-highlighting-in-some-tags). But maybe it will work this time. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've enabled the "default" syntax highlighting for the [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) tag, which makes the answer you linked to look more colourful; [How do I write to a file in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444264/how-do-i-write-to-a-file-in-kotlin/35445704#35445704)

If you do find a [more suitable supported highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100), let me know and I can switch it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's much nicer. I understand to have a highlighter, somebody has to implement it.

Comment: @Tichodroma: For *new* highlighters, then yes... somebody has to implement it. However, what you often find is that you can re-use an existing highlighter, even if it wasn't specifically written for a language.

Comment: I've written a syntax highlighter for Kotlin (see my answer). I'd appreciate if you could make it the default one for the [tag:kotlin] tag

Answer (score 11):

[It's not going to come anytime soon. The request has been denied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299920/support-kotlin-in-code-highlighting)

---

I've [written a syntax highlighter for Kotlin](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/496) and on the 15th of August 2017 it has been merged to the [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) repository (what StackOverflow uses). <s>StackOverflow should update it's code-prettify's version shortly.</s>